# VB 2008-calling a function across forms

Tags: vb.net

This is my program.

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim adult As Decimal

    Public Function getadult(ByRef adult As Decimal) As Decimal
        Return adult
    End Function

    Public Function setadult(ByVal value As Decimal) As Decimal
        adult = value
    End Function

    Public Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles adultrate.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Call setadult(adultrate.Text)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Form2.Show()
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class Form2

    Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim adult As Decimal
        Call getadult(adult)
        MsgBox("the rate for adults is " & adult)
    End Sub

End Class
```

I cant successfully call the function adult and its value to another form. It works great if i use it within the same form. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Way to pass data between forms (VB 2008)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637422/way-to-pass-data-between-forms-vb-2008)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest option is to add a Module to your project, and place your code there.

You should also be using a property...

```
Dim _adult As Decimal
Public Property adult As Decimal
    Get
        Return _adult
    End Get
    Set (byval value As Decimal)
        _adult = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Both of your forms will have access to this property.

To set and get your property simply use;

```
adult = cdec(adultrate.Text)
adultrate.Text = adult
```

So for your code...

**Form1:**

```
Public Class Form1

    Public Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles adultrate.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        adult = CDec(adultrate.Text)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Form2.Show()
    End Sub

End Class
```

**Form2:**

```
Public Class Form2

    Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MsgBox("The rate for adults is " & adult)
    End Sub

End Class
```

**Module:**

```
Module Module1

    Dim _adult As Decimal
    Public Property adult As Decimal
        Get
            Return _adult
        End Get
        Set (byval value As Decimal)
            _adult = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Module
```

Of course, you could just have a public variable in your module too.....

Comment: Please see my quick edit... Missed an underscore ;-)

Comment: i did what you told .... i still cannot call properties across forms.... i added the code you told in a module and i did a Call getadult(adult) in a form and it didnt work.

Comment: i jus dont get it .... its a dim (global) variable and a public property but still calling it in another form gets me a error..

Comment: ok..... am i calling it right?           call "setadult" and call " getadult" right? .... or jus tell me how to call it

Comment: You're not doing a call here... You're property works like a variable does, rather than a method.

Comment: im sorry.. what is the "get" command again? "adultrate.Text audult"??? i set the value using "adult = cdec(adultrate.Text)" now i jus need to call it .

Comment: Yeah, sorry, there was a missing = sign and a typo there... Silly me!!

Comment: You can use the adult property just like a variable now in any form...  adult = blahblah.... and blahblah = adult...

Comment: Man ........many thanks ...... u  answered and finished my 74 hour long search.... live long and prosper